# Dash panel is not visible

Tags: 11.10, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I recently upgraded Ubuntu from version 11.04 to 11.10.  After about two days of using this new version the Dash didn't appear on the top, and I wasn't able to access the programs that I use.  Let me describe:

The bar on the top with the clock and Internet connections is not there.  The only remains are the notification messages that a connection has been found, which allows me to connect to the Internet; and the menus from what appear to be a nautilus application but I'm not sure, they read File Edit View Go Bookmarks Help, and they open my Home Folder.

The icons of my favourite applications are not there, and I am unable to access them wit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or the <kbd>Super</kbd> key.  The only thing that's available is the Terminal with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

By the way, in order to keep using the computer I had to run the Ubuntu 2D version at the beginning, but as you would imagine that is not optimal since I was already looking forward to the new features of Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: A screenshot would help a lot.

Comment: Fortunately I found the problem.  For the future, I'll remember to add a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, which should reinstall all of Unity's features.

Comment: I'm not sure the command will do anything - if ubuntu-desktop is installed, it'll just say "ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version" and do nothing.

Comment: Thank you.  The Unity plugin in Compiz got disabled.  Now I know.

Answer (score 1):

> `[from the original question asker]`

It turns out I accidentally uninstalled the Unity plugin in *CompizConig Settings Manager*. I renabled the Unity plugin in the same application.

[image: Screenshot of CCSM]